# Copy Entire Command Prompt History

Tags: windows-7, command-line, history

So I'm running windows 7 and I have a long program that runs through command prompt and I need the output of it. I put my Buffer Size and Number of Buffers to `999` but I still am unable to get the entire history from when my program starts running. Suggestions on how maybe I can either print the history to a file or copy the whole thing?

Comment: What are you missing and how are you copying it? Are you redirecting the program’s output or using the console’s mark-copy function?

Comment: I'm trying to copy it via Select All / Copy and it won't get it all since the history has been erased (or I can't see it when I scroll up). The problem with alot of answers is I'm compiling through visual studio, but I did not put that in my question :/

Comment: Is your program outputting more than 999 lines?

Comment: No my program doesn't ouput nearly that many lines, but is probably only showing 100 lines, 150 tops.

Comment: So your program is printing ~100 lines and your command-prompt’s buffer is set to 999, but when you scroll up, it does not show all of the expected lines. Is that correct? Can you determine how many lines it *does* show and/or how many lines are missing? Maybe one of those numbers will look familiar (i.e., check the properties dialog for those numbers in one of the fields). Does the program clear the screen between printed “pages”? Try setting the console to the smallest prompt and the window to the largest width and height so that you can see more lines at a time to see if that has an effect.

Comment: Is there anything special about the missing text? For example, is it being printed to `stderr` instead of `stdout`? What happens if you redirect to a file?

Answer (score 6):

Windows [has something similar](http://blog.crankybit.com/redirecting-output-to-a-file-in-windows-batch-scripts/) to the **redirection operators** in Linux.

The exact same syntax can be used:

> progname > outputfile.txt

This will wipe the file of its old contents and fill it with the output of `progname`.

If you should need to append to the file (add more without wiping out the old contents), use the below syntax:

> progname >> outputfile.txt

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called "redirection", and can be done in any terminal/command prompt. Just use `command_to_run > filename_to_save_into`.

Also note that a double-arrow will *append* to a file, as in `command_to_run >> filename_to_append_onto`.

Answer (score 2):

To send the output to the clipboard append `| clip`.

Ex: `ping example.com | clip`

[image: CLIP]

From my clipboard:

```
Pinging example.com [192.0.43.10] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.0.43.10: bytes=32 time=70ms TTL=244
Reply from 192.0.43.10: bytes=32 time=103ms TTL=244
Reply from 192.0.43.10: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=244
Reply from 192.0.43.10: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=244

Ping statistics for 192.0.43.10:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 103ms, Average = 52ms
```

Comment: I never knew that! +1

Answer (score 0):

Besides redirection, you can also increase the buffer size of the command prompt. Details are explained here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491037.aspx

> 1. Open Command Prompt
> 2. Click the upper-left corner of the Command Prompt window, and then
>      click Properties.
> 3. Click the Options tab.
> 4. In Command History, type or select 999 in Buffer Size, and then type
>      or select 5 in Number of Buffers.
> 5. In Edit Options, select the Quick Edit Mode and Insert Mode check
>      boxes.
> 6. Click the Layout tab.
> 7. In Screen Buffer Size, type or select 2500 in Height.
> 8. Do any of the following optional tasks:
>
>    - In Screen Buffer Size, increase Width.
>    - In Window Size, increase Height.
>    - In Window Size, increase Width.
>    - Clear the Let system position window check box, and then, in Window Position, change the values in Left and Top.
> 9. In the Apply Properties dialog box, click Save properties for future
>      windows with same title.

In the *Note* section

> - By increasing the screen buffer size to 999, you enable scrolling through the Command Prompt window.
> - By increasing the number of buffers to five, you increase the number of lines in the Command Prompt window to 5000.

Comment: The Command History buffer size has nothing to do with how much information the window displays.  It controls how many previously typed commands it will remember.  Step 7, change the Screen Buffer Height, is the useful step there.